# In Dropout(0.8)(x), what is (x) meant for?

Tags: python, keras

In the following Python code, what does the `(x)` mean?

```py
Dropout(0.8)(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(x)` uses the preceding function reference (returned by `Dropout(0.8)`) to make a function call with `x` as the argument.

For example:

```
def Dropout(a):
    def func(b):
        return a + b
    return func
x = 0.2
print(Dropout(0.8)(x))
```

would output `1.0`.